# OpenLDAP check database

Tags: openldap

favorite

I'm using now OpenLDAP server ( `slapd` ) to manage my authentication / authorization mechanism. I have an issue:

something slapd process doesn't restart for error in database ( about some entry ) or configuration error.

Now, I use to check configuration `sldaptest -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d/` command line, but to check any corruption errors in database ?

I have daily dump in ldif of my datas, but I would like be sure that this dump is error-free.

Thanks

Details:

OS: Ubuntu 14.04
kernel:3.13.0-43generic
slapd version: 2.4.31

My script:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonymous auth by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write by * none
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write by * read
olcAccess: {3}to dn.subtree="dc=th,dc=company,dc=com" by set="[cn=app_all,ou=Groups,dc=th,dc=company,dc=com]/member*" write by * read
```

Comment: Before suspecting actual corruption, make sure that your LDAP data files are actually owned by `openldap` user (or whatever account your slapd runs as). I've been bit by "Oops, datafiles or the directory they are in is owned by root" thing way too many times.

Comment: Instead editing title with `solved` word, please post the solution in answer section below and [mark it accepted](http://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that if the dump finishes without an error, you can assume it to be correct. To be extra sure, you could configure a separate database inside OpenLDAP and import the dump back into this db.

Beside that, having random data or config errors is not normal, this should **never** happen. You need to investigate this and fix the problem causing it.

Comment: sometimes add new ACL  by `ldapmodify` using replace of all existing plus new ones, and during restart of slapd, error of bad configuration happens. So I need to clear dump of configuration and import again.

Comment: Solved.

Inside script there are some spaces or white characters that I cannot see inside LDIF exports.

Comment: ACL script present need to have space at the end of the line, in line 2-3

    dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config<space>
    changetype: modify<space>
    replace: olcAccess<space>
    ...